# I want to modified my JSON output using JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, dynamic-arrays

My JSON output like that

```
{"intent":"P&P_Purchase","value1":{"date1":"30-Dec-19","prd_desc":"NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG)","qty":"18MT","inv_no":"NRKT07003160"},"value2":{"date1":"25-Dec-19","prd_desc":"NEEM UREA IMP (45 KG)","qty":"18MT","inv_no":"NRKT07003107"},"value3":{"date1":"19-Dec-19","prd_desc":"DAP IMP","qty":"20MT","inv_no":"NRKT07003058"},"value4":{"date1":"16-Dec-19","prd_desc":"NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG)","qty":"18MT","inv_no":"NRKT07003043"},"value5":{"date1":"30-Nov-19","prd_desc":"NEEM UREA IMP (45 KG)","qty":"54MT","inv_no":"NRKT07002921"},"value6":null,"value7":null,"value8":null,"value9":null,"value10":null}
```

What i want replace **value1 ={"date1":"30-Dec-19","prd_desc":"NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG)","qty":"18MT","inv_no":"NRKT07003160"}** into like **value1 = Date:30-Dec-19,Product:NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG), Quantity :18MT,inv_no :NRKT07003160**

Here is my existing code

```
    var sdata = JSON.stringify(data);
    const options = {
           method: 'POST',
           uri: 'http://chatbotWebservice/resources/webservice/service' ,
           body: JSON.parse(sdata) ,
           json: true
           }
        return request(options)
            .then( body => {
                var unit =  body
                unit.intent = "P&P_Purchase"
                unit.value1 = unit.level3purpay[0]
console.log(unit.level3purpay[0].prd_desc)
                unit.value2 = unit.level3purpay[1]
                unit.value3 = unit.level3purpay[2]
                unit.value4 = unit.level3purpay[3]
                unit.value5 = unit.level3purpay[4]
                unit.value6 = null
                unit.value7 = null
                unit.value8 = null
                unit.value9 = null
                unit.value10 = null
                delete unit.level3purpay
                var unit2 = JSON.stringify(unit)
                console.log(unit2)
          conv.ask(unit2);

              })
              .catch( err => {
               console.error( err );
               conv.ask('Something went wrong. What should I do now?');
                 });
```

I can share more information if required. Thank you and Please help me Out on this.

Comment: Please share what is stopping you from completing your task.

Comment: You want to replace object key names right ?

Comment: I am trying to code for this but i can't@Lain

Comment: Yes I want replace object key as well as brackets@SameerKhan

Answer (score 2):

Use `Object.entries`, `map` and `join` to form into a string.

```js
const value1 = {
  date1: "30-Dec-19",
  prd_desc: "NEEM UREA OMIFCO (45 KG)",
  qty: "18MT",
  inv_no: "NRKT07003160"
};

const labels = {
  date1: "Date",
  prd_desc: "Product",
  qty: "Quantity",
  inv_no: "inv_no"
};

const new_value1 = Object.entries(value1)
  .map(([key, value]) => `${labels[key]}:${value}`)
  .join();

console.log(new_value1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value1.Product=value1.prd_desc
```

for adding the value

```
delete value1.prd_dsc
```

for deleting(you shouldn't do it like that unless you know exactly what you're doing)
an other approach would be to copy the data

```
value1={date1:value1.date1,Product:value1.prd_desc}
```